# How to include child resources in Firebase API call

Tags: json, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database with the following structure

- Stories
- Cards
- Photos
- Users

Relationally, each story has multiple cards, which in turn have multiple photos.

Is it possible to use the Firebase REST API such that when I make an API call to get a list of stories, it will also include the related children Cards and Photos?

```
https://[project].firebaseio.com/stories.json?print=pretty
```

Note that in the firebase database, these are not nested within the parent, but as separate lists.

Comment: Can a card be used with multiple stories and likewise, can a photo be used on multiple cards? Or is it all 1-1?

Comment: @Jay Nope, a card or photo belongs to a single story only

Comment: I am all about denormalization and 'flatter is better' for NoSQL. However, it appears in this use case, you may want to consider including the cards and photos as children of the stories node so when you read in a story, you have all of the data specified in the question.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Jay. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is more information, from your comment, it appears your data is all 1-1 relationships and in that case, there's no reason to separate it out.

So structure your data

```
Stories
  Cards
  Photos
Users
```

when you load a story, it loads the cards and photos that go with it so with once observe, you get everything needed.

That being said... Denormalization is generally a the way to go when the data has anything other than 1-1 relationships or if it's more complex than in this question.